# Squid (proxy) is eating up its own resources (and other issues)

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, https, squid

I have several squid issues, but one at a time:

**WARNING! Your cache is running out of filedescriptors**

This can happen when the proxy are getting a lot of calls, and can be fixed by increasing the limit, but mine isn't even "*open*" yet..

I found out that it's squid somehow constantly connecting to it self?

(from my access.log)

```
1628674032.019  59108 192.168.0.129 NONE/200 0 CONNECT 192.168.0.129:3129 - ORIGINAL_DST/192.168.0.129 -
1628674032.019  59098 192.168.0.129 NONE/200 0 CONNECT 192.168.0.129:3129 - ORIGINAL_DST/192.168.0.129 -
1628674032.019  59087 192.168.0.129 NONE/200 0 CONNECT 192.168.0.129:3129 - ORIGINAL_DST/192.168.0.129 -
```

My configuration was originally created by pfsense, but is used on a stand-alone squid running on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
# This file is automatically generated by pfSense
# Do not edit manually !
acl all src all
http_access allow all
http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=10MB cert=/usr/local/squid/etc/ssl_cert/myCA.pem  cafile=/usr/local/squid/etc/ssl_cert/myCA.crt capath=/usr/local/squid/etc/rootca/ cipher=EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!SHA1:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS tls-dh=prime256v1:/usr/local/squid/etc/dhparam.pem options=NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE

https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=10MB cert=/usr/local/squid/etc/ssl_cert/myCA.pem cafile=/usr/local/squid/etc/rootca/ca-root-nss.crt capath=/usr/local/squid/etc/rootca/ cipher=EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!SHA1:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS tls-dh=prime256v1:/usr/local/squid/etc/dhparam.pem options=NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE

#tcp_outgoing_address 10.10.66.1
icp_port 0
#digest_generation off
dns_v4_first on
#pid_filename /var/run/squid/squid.pid  
cache_effective_user proxy
cache_effective_group proxy
error_default_language en
#icon_directory /usr/local/etc/squid/icons
visible_hostname Satan
cache_mgr admin@localhost
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
cache_store_log none
netdb_filename /var/log/squid/netdb.state
pinger_enable on
pinger_program /usr/lib/squid/pinger
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib/squid/security_file_certgen -s /usr/local/squid/var/logs/ssl_db -M 4MB -b 4096

tls_outgoing_options cafile=/usr/local/squid/etc/rootca/ca-root-nss.crt 
tls_outgoing_options capath=/usr/local/squid/etc/rootca/
tls_outgoing_options options=NO_SSLv3,NO_TLSv1,SINGLE_DH_USE,SINGLE_ECDH_USE
tls_outgoing_options cipher=EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!SHA1:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS
sslcrtd_children 5

logfile_rotate 10
debug_options rotate=0
shutdown_lifetime 3 seconds
# Allow local network(s) on interface(s)
acl localnet src  192.168.0.0/24
forwarded_for delete
via off
httpd_suppress_version_string on
uri_whitespace strip

acl dynamic urlpath_regex cgi-bin \?
cache deny dynamic

cache_mem 2048 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 8192 KB
memory_replacement_policy heap GDSF
cache_replacement_policy heap LFUDA
minimum_object_size 0 KB
maximum_object_size 16 MB
cache_dir aufs /cache 10000 16 256
offline_mode off
cache_swap_low 90
cache_swap_high 95
cache allow all
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:    1440  20%  10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:  1440  0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0  0%  0
refresh_pattern .    0  20%  4320


#Remote proxies


# Setup some default acls
# ACLs all, manager, localhost, and to_localhost are predefined.
acl allsrc src all
acl safeports port 21 70 80 210 280 443 488 563 591 631 777 901  3128 3129 1025-65535 
acl sslports port 443 563  

acl purge method PURGE
acl connect method CONNECT

# Define protocols used for redirects
acl HTTP proto HTTP
acl HTTPS proto HTTPS

# SslBump Peek and Splice
# http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice
# http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/SslBumpExplicit
# Match against the current step during ssl_bump evaluation [fast]
# Never matches and should not be used outside the ssl_bump context.
#
# At each SslBump step, Squid evaluates ssl_bump directives to find
# the next bumping action (e.g., peek or splice). Valid SslBump step
# values and the corresponding ssl_bump evaluation moments are:
#   SslBump1: After getting TCP-level and HTTP CONNECT info.
#   SslBump2: After getting TLS Client Hello info.
#   SslBump3: After getting TLS Server Hello info.
# These ACLs exist even when 'SSL/MITM Mode' is set to 'Custom' so that
# they can be used there for custom configuration.
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3
http_access allow manager localhost

http_access deny manager
http_access allow purge localhost
http_access deny purge
http_access deny !safeports
http_access deny CONNECT !sslports

# Always allow localhost connections
http_access allow localhost

request_body_max_size 0 KB
delay_pools 1
delay_class 1 2
delay_parameters 1 -1/-1 -1/-1
delay_initial_bucket_level 100
delay_access 1 allow allsrc

# Reverse Proxy settings


# Custom options before auth


ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
# Setup allowed ACLs
# Allow local network(s) on interface(s)
http_access allow localnet
# Default block all to be sure
http_access deny allsrc
```

other bonus questions are:

<strike>2. Do I need a **http** configuration (port 3128) when I'm only using https/ssl</strike>

2. **Yes**, apparently it's necessary
3. **acl all src all** (the first command in the configuration) results the following in syslog. It's only a warning, but how do I fix it?

---

```
Aug 11 12:28:46 socks squid[2718]: WARNING: because of this '::/0' is ignored to keep splay tree searching predictable
Aug 11 12:28:46 socks squid[2718]: WARNING: You should probably remove '::/0' from the ACL named 'all'
```

---

4. If you find anything else that's wrong, please say so, and if possible, explain why (so we can learn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad guy in this scenario was actually a disabled option..

*#tcp_outgoing_address 10.10.66.1*

For some kind of reasons, the squid server didn't apparently know where to send the out-data, and sent it to itself, causing an neverending loop.

by enabling this command, and point it to my external ip, by doing this, a loopback was avoidable.

For me, this would be an unnecessary command, and can't understand why it's necessary, squid should know where the internet is..